Problem in fetching the image from gallery in flutter over the icon by using imagepicker
This is the code for selecting the image in flutter but when i select the image from the gallery it does not show on the icon and when i select camera for taking the image it does not open the camera instead it opens the gallery why?
try to run my project over Chrome(web)
file
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:harsh/uihelper.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class SignUpPagee extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignUpPagee({super.key});

  @override
  State<SignUpPagee> createState() => _SignUpPageeState();
}

class _SignUpPageeState extends State<SignUpPagee> {
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordConntroller= TextEditingController();
  File? pickedImage;
  showAlertBox(){
    return showDialog(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context){
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text("pick image from "),
        content: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            ListTile(
              onTap: (){
                pickImage(ImageSource.camera);
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              leading: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
              title: Text("Camera"),
            ),
            ListTile(
              onTap: (){
                pickImage(ImageSource.gallery);
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
             leading: Icon(Icons.image),
              title: Text("Gallery"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("SignUpPage2"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          InkWell(
            onTap: (){
              showAlertBox();
            },
            child:pickedImage!=null? CircleAvatar(
              radius: 80,
             backgroundImage: FileImage(pickedImage!),
            ):
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 88,
                  child: Icon(Icons.person,size: 80,),
                )
          ),
          UiHelper.CustomTextField(emailController, "Email", Icons.mail, false),
          UiHelper.CustomTextField(passwordConntroller, "Password", Icons.password, false),
          SizedBox(height: 20,),
          UiHelper.CustomButton(() { }, "Sign Up "),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  pickImage(ImageSource imageSource)async{
    try{
      final photo= await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: imageSource);
      if(photo==null)return;
        final tempimage= File(photo.path);
        setState(() {
          pickedImage= tempimage;

        });


    }
    catch(ex){
      log(ex.toString() as num);
    }
  }
  
}

pubspec.yml file
name: harsh
description: "A new Flutter project."
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.2.4 <4.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^2.27.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.17.8
  cloud_firestore: ^4.15.8
  image_picker: ^1.0.8

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages

i am trying to take the image selected by me from the gallery over the circle avatar but when i select the image from the gallery it does not comes on the icon what i use in making the Ui of my project.
also when i select camera for taking the image it does not opens the instead it opens gallery everytime.

The image picker package you are using doesn't work for web. There is another package image_picker_for_web. Just like the image_picker library, it is a published by the flutter team

 - you can not access file directly because flutter web do not directly provide file access for security you can picked image and display in web easy way follow below code.
 - in this code firstly picked image path after picked image path you can pass this path in Image.network()
        

 - image_picker: ^1.1.2
        

 - GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => pickedImage(),
      child: Container(
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
             border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
         ),
         child: imagePath.isNotEmpty
               ? Image.network(imagePath, fit: BoxFit.fill,)
               : const Center(child: Text("Tap to Select Image"),
         )
      ),
   ),
        

 - void pickedImage() async{
      final imagePicker = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
       if(imagePicker != null){
           setState((){
              imagePath = imagePicker.path;
          });
      }}

